# "html/main.html: not found" error in kdb web application

Tags: kdb

I'm developing a web application using websocket by taking reference from https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/websockets/.

The application resides at path:

```
Directory structure:
/Users/repos/chatu/
    -->html
          --> main.html
          --> main.js
    -->q
          --> main.q


q)\pwd
"/Users/repos/chatu" //- and main.html(index) is at path /Users/repos/chatu/html/main.html
```

When the pwd is "/Users/repos/chatu" then the webpage is opening properly on browser using url - http://localhost:5001/main.html

But when the pwd is changed to any other directory such as

```
q)\pwd
"/Users/repos"
```

Then hitting same url as above throws below error :

```
html/main.html: not found
```

What I can understand from the error is that web server is expecting the html/main.html at the current working directory and it is not able to find that.

How/Where can I set absolute path for index.html that from any current working directory the web browser can find the main.html page?(Cannot find/understand any answer which solves same problem).

```
Code snippet -
main.js
function connect(){
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001/");
        output.value="connecting...";
        /* ws.onopen=function(e){output.innerHTML="connected"}; */
        ws.onclose=function(e){output.innerHTML="disconnected"};
        ws.onerror=function(e){output.value=e.data};
        /*
            when a message is received,
            prepend the message to the display area
            along with the input command
        */
        } else alert("WebSockets not supported on your browser.");
    }

main.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chatu</title>
    <style>
        /* define some CSS styling on page elements */
        div#wrap{
            width:100%;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        textarea#txtInput {width: 97.5%; height: 60px; float:left; padding: 10px; margin-top: 10px;}
        div#txtOutput{
            width: 97.5%; height: 300px; font-family: "Courier New"; padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid gray; margin-top: 2px; overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<fieldset id='heads' style="border:1; border-radius:10px">
    <legend align="center" style="color:blue">Chatu</legend>
    <div id="txtOutput"></div>
    <textarea id="txtInput" autofocus></textarea>
</fieldset>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>

main.q
.z.ws:{neg[.z.w].j.j @[.da.mf;x;{`$ "'",x}];};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.h.HOME is the variable you are interested in

https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/doth/#hhome-webserver-root

Answer (score 4):

I believe the way you can set an absolute path for index html as you have described in your kdb web application is assigning this path using .h.HOME.

The variable .h.HOME is a string which contains the location of the webserver root.

If you would like a more detailed explanation on .h.HOME refer to https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/doth/#hhome-webserver-root